# How to resolve 'TemplateDoesNotExist' error when Django appears to be searching the correct path

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm setting up the structure for a new project in Django. I've created the app 'accounts', within which I've added a templates folder containing an html template. However, when I go into the development server and click on a link to this page from my index page (which loads no problem), it returns a TemplateDoesNotExist error message.

I've examined the error message and the Template-loader postmortem details the correct pathway for my html template (I've checked this and made sure countless times), suggesting that Django is looking in the right place for it. However, it also says 'source does not exist'. Does anybody have any troubleshooting tips, considering Django appears to be searching the correct pathway?

```
# From settings.py ('accounts' is also included with INSTALLED_APPS):

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# ...

'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

# From urls.py:

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from accounts.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', index, name="index"),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]

# From urls.py (accounts):

from .views import signup

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', signup, name="signup"),
]

# From views.py (accounts):

def signup(request):
    return render(request, 'signup')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess do you have a newer version of django on your server machine.

[`DIRS` is now (2.2)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-the-project-s-templates-directory) into `TEMPLATES` setting var. On [django old version (ex: 1.8)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#dirs) was in `DIRS` setting var.

Then, **check** versions and move to newest one and use:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

on settings.

Comment: I was running Django 1.11 purely because I'm used to the syntax. I've created a new environment with Django 2.2.2 and everything seems to be working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @samalty , awesome! Welcome to Stack Overflow:[What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)